# How to prepare for mySQL too many requests?

Tags: php, mysql

> Thanks for taking time to my problem.
>   I am new to MySQL.

My problem is I want to make many (about 1000 clients' requests) `select`/`insert` queries to a MySQL database within a second.

I found there is a proper limit on it about 250-500 concurrents or there will be unhandled hardware over usage of server if there is no limit.

But I need to run about 1000 concurrent queries within a second.

And I searched for my problem and I found Master/Slave method (but I've not understand it well). And I am having to ask for it, if I split *Read* to slave, and *Write* to Master, how about concurrent connections will be solved, Please if you could explain it in detail, thanks in advance.

And I think 1000 requests at a time is not a heavy range. so I think there would not be hardware over usage for my server. Could you please suggest me for my problem.

The main language using is PHP. I am currently trying to solve it with creating a `json` files as replicates of database and clients' select requests will go to them. Server scripts refresh them per 3 seconds. May I know it is a good or very bad idea to solve this problem.

Comment: How many select statements do you expect? Those statements can be cached easily, while insert queries can't. Are those select statements unique, or do you expect many duplicate queries?

Comment: @StephanVierkant, select statements will not be duplicated because they are from unique clients (Android App). It will be about 1000 requests at a time for a most peak second. Thank you.

Comment: @RyanVincent, I am using mysql/php now and before. But my windows server (by plesk - dual cpu / 32 GB Ram) is already running with many requests and sometime it is facing the problem like "out of resource" or heavy loading time to success a statement. So I want to avoid these problems on my new server and new apps (requests are from android app). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically number of IOPS (Input/output operations per second) is limited by your hardware (how fast and big is your hard drive, how many GB of RAM do you have and how fast CPU do you have).

In your question you are asking for concurrent connections and number of queries per second. This are not the same things.

[The maximum permitted value for number of simultaneous connections is 32 767](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187030.aspx) as you can see you are not limited in any way by database engine.

There isn't any fix limit of maximum queries per second if you are thinking about database engine. However as I mentioned at the beginning you are limited by your hardware.

You need to be aware that one simple select question is much faster to execute then complex select question with multiple joins.

To sum up. If you have fast enough server 1 000 queries per second is not a problem.

Comment: Thanks, it will be the best !